# DATE_SUB() vs DATE - interval

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, date-arithmetic

Seeing a lot of queries not using the DATE_SUB() function and instead subtracting by doing
'DATE' - interval x day. I think there's a difference but I'm looking to understand what is happening when they subtract directly like that.

Comment: its the same thing that happens when we do `date_expr + INTERVAL -5 DAY`

Comment: @spencer7593 And that form is commutative [db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f7e857c4266512b5506ef9b960376bb7) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know there's a difference

No, there is no difference. Typically, these two statements return the same result:

```
select current_date - interval 5 day;
-- is the same as
select date_sub(current_date, interval 5 day);
```

These are equivalent, and both are perfectly valid ways to do date artihmetics in MySQL. Which one you choose is mostly a matter of taste. As for me, I like the explicit substraction better, because it is standard date arithmetics, while `date_sub()` is MySQL-specific.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I was mistaken.